# Does VS2010 contain inbuilt wdk in it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Previously i was using the WDK drivers separately to set the environment.

But just i came to know that VS2010 contain inbuilt wdk package in it. If it contains, how to use it. how we can start building through VS2010 ? I am currently wanted to use free build for x64 platform.

can anyone help me out in this context. I need some screen short, since m new to VS. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, to my knowledge WDK is still a self-contained kit and you can't use VS2010 to build your drivers -- this is still done by running "make" and using an appropriate makefile from WDK that is distributed separately.

You can, however, use VS2010 as a code editor with syntax highlight and autocompletion to edit the source code of your driver. Any other free editor, like Notepad++ or JEdit would also do here.

I would recommend you to read the following very nice document for the start with WDK:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463002